# Docker Swarm and Netfilter

Tags: nginx, debian, iptables, asp.net, docker-swarm

I have deployed a Docker Swarm server on my VPS, to handle an Asp.Net Core application. I want to serve this app through a Nginx web server.

Let's suppose my web app is a vanilla app I created through .Net Core CLI command:

```
dotnet new webapp mywebapp
```

Dockerfile (simplified):

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0-alpine as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o publish
WORKDIR /app/publish
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyWebApp.dll"]
```

My `docker-compose.yml` looks like this (simplified):

```
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    image: edouard/mywebapp:latest
    ports:
      - 9000:80
```

My nginx config looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name myservername.com;

    ssl_certificate     /path/to/ssl_certificate;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/ssl_certificate_key;

   location / {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:9000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    } 

}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myservername.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

As you can see, I use Nginx as reverse proxy server, redirecting all HTTP/HTTPS traffic from 80 and 443 ports to the local 9000 port, which Docker Swarm is mapping to the 80 port inside the container, on which a Kestrel server is running.

On `https://myservername.com`, everything is running fine. But here is the thing: people can also access to my web app on `http://myservername.com:9000`! This is something I don't want.

I guess I have to configure the firewall so that I only allow traffic to the 80 and 443 port (taking care of letting the 22 port for SSH, etc.). I have read some tutorials to know how to do this, however, Docker Swarm is also handling the firewall!

When I launch `sudo iptables -L -v`:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 3417  873K DOCKER-USER  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
 3417  873K DOCKER-INGRESS  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
   31  9043 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    docker0  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 DOCKER     all  --  any    docker0  anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 !docker0  anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 docker0  anywhere             anywhere            
   18  7620 ACCEPT     all  --  any    docker_gwbridge  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 DOCKER     all  --  any    docker_gwbridge  anywhere             anywhere            
   13  1423 ACCEPT     all  --  docker_gwbridge !docker_gwbridge  anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 DROP       all  --  docker_gwbridge docker_gwbridge  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  docker0 !docker0  anywhere             anywhere            
   13  1423 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  docker_gwbridge !docker_gwbridge  anywhere             anywhere            
   31  9043 RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       all  --  any    docker0  anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 DROP       all  --  any    docker_gwbridge  anywhere             anywhere            
   13  1423 RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 3417  873K RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-INGRESS (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 1567  101K ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:9000
 1270  698K ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED tcp spt:9000
   31  9043 RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
```

How am I suppose to configure the firewall so that it doesn't interact with Docker Swarm?
I have found some parts of answers:

- [This one](https://www.sysnove.fr/blog/2019/02/firewall-devant-docker-swarm.html) (sorry it's in French)
- which is referencing [this one](https://unrouted.io/2017/08/15/docker-firewall/)

However, I find it pretty complicated, and I am astonished that there is no official answer to this issue on Docker's blogs.

Versions:

- VPS: Debian 10.2
- Docker Engine: 19.03.5
- Nginx: 1.16.1
- Iptables: 1.8.2

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try binding localhost instead of default 0.0.0.0 address:

```
services:
  app:
    image: edouard/mywebapp:latest
    ports:
      - '127.0.0.1:9000:80'
```

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports

Comment: Hello saf, thanks for your answer. If I'm not mistaken, this should solve my problem but seems like a "quick & dirty" fix. Maybe there is a way to configure it at the Docker engine scale? (without having to do it for each application I deploy)

Comment: The issue is still open. https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2999